# Wrapping a method from outside the class in Python

Tags: python, methods, decorator, word-wrap

Let say I have some imported class named *TheClass* and a method *sth(arg)*.

What I have:

```
var = TheClass()
var.sth('blah')
```

What I want:

```
var = TheClass()
var.wrapped_sth()
```

where wrapped_sth is something like:

```
def wrapped_sth():
    sth('blah')
```

I already know that it should be done with a decorator, however all the examples I already found were cases where you have access to *TheClass* implementation, which I don't have and I don't want to override.

Hope the description is clear. Can you help me?

Comment: You will need override with a decorator.

Comment: So, you want to wrap a class' method without creating a child class? Or you can create a child class but you just want to wrap and not override the method?

Comment: @gionni, I already tried that second solution, but then there was other problem, like some attributes missing, coz other methods were looking for some properties that I hadn't had.

Comment: What I meant was exactly what @Alyss answered

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to extend `TheClass` to wrap the function.

```
class MyClass(TheClass):
   def wrapped_sth(self):
       return self.sth('blah')
```

Now you can create `var = MyClass()`, and call `var.wrapped_sth()` as desired, and `MyClass` will inherit all the functions from `TheClass`.

Answer (score 3):

You're coding your decorator incorrectly, to correct that:

```
def decorator_sth(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func('blah')
    return wrapper
```

Now wrap the method using `decorator_sth`:

```
var.sth = decorator(var.sth)         # this call returns wrapper
```

`decorator_sth` takes a function and returns a wrapper function. `func` is the decorated function, `wrapper` is the wrapper function. The `wrapper` function retains `func` from the enclosing scope, from the local scope of `decorator_sth`.

This is a typical decorator; it takes a function or a callable object as an argument and returns either the callable itself or a wrapper object around it.

Comment: Thank you too, altough I will go with @Alyss solution. However it's good to know how it should be done correctly.